# Having Trouble Getting to Laverre City

Tags: pokemon-x-y

My young son is having trouble getting to Laverre City in Pokemon X.  Can somebody please give me a hint?

Comment: Where exactly is he stuck? It's straight north of Lumoise through the swamp. Is the power restored in Lumoise yet?

Comment: @BenBrocka - thanks for the comment.  Apparently he missed the part where he was supposed to meet professor Sycamore in the cafe.

Comment: So, now that this question is solved, and no general answer can be given... what do we do?

Comment: Maybe the question can be rephrased as "How do I get to Laverre City?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for: "How do I get to Laverre City" as suggested in the comments
You also need cut and surf if you want to obtain every item, but I'll just explain how to get to Laverre City. Check the link below to see a guide for every item.

1. Enter the route from the Lumiose city <-> route 14 gate.
2. Meet up with your friends in the playground.
3. Travel north into the swamp and go left at the first T junction. (There will be a female ranger there)
4. Go up once again (past the male ranger)
5. Follow the path right.
6. Go past the hex maniac girl and go up again.
7. Slightly north-west of the ranger running around in circles is a small intersection of paths. Go left.
8. Enter the house, follow the storyline, then exit and go back to the intersection.
9. This time, go up.
10. Welcome to Laverre City.

---

Source:

- Just navigated the route
- http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kalos_Route_14

Answer (score 0):

if he is having trouble, i take it he has met up with his neighbors at the scary house. If he hasn't done this: go forward until you meet the first trainer, then go left. Go forwards, then right, then up to the massive pool of water. Go to the top left corner of the pool,(the scary house is to the left) then go up. You will reach Laverre City! Also you can beat the gym without having to fight any trainers apart from the gym leader.